# Can't copy/move file folder

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave

I am having challenges moving/copying file folder from My MacBook to external hdd or VMware. I have attached screenshot of the folders. the first one with the face icon is not moveable while the other one is. apparently all the folders with that face icon aren't moveable. I have checked if the folder is lock using the Get-info but it's not. all permission are set to RWX. don't know what to else to do. any body having same challenge.???[image: File Folder image]

Comment: What are the absolute paths to the vxm and Organic Chemistry folders?

Comment: Please edit your question to describe specifically what error you get when trying to copy this folder.